# oracle query with nulls last on order by clause not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data like this for a department say computer science(CSE) with dept_id = 70. All the rows until the last comes from one table and average for that department comes from a different query with union all.

Pseudo-query:

```
SELECT id, dept, name, from_date, to_date, mi, avg, dept_id 
FROM (SELECT id , dept, name, from_date, to_date, mi, avg, dept_id  
      FROM dept_vw vw 
      
      UNION

      SELECT NULL AS id, dept, NULL AS name, NULL AS fromDate, NULL AS toDate, null AS mi, round(avg,2) AS avg, dept_id
      FROM avg_vw) 
ORDER BY dept_id DESC, toDate DESC NULLS LAST;
```

```
id  dept name   fromDate    toDate      mi  avg dept_id
12  CSE BRADLEY 01-APR-15   25-JUN-15   CH  3.69    70
22  CSE ASHLEY  01-FEB-15   15-JUN-15   EN      70
30  CSE GARCES  01-APR-14   16-FEB-15   TR  3.77    70
25  CSE LYNCH   04-OCT-14   15-FEB-15   CH  3.08    70
35  CSE STRONG  27-NOV-14   15-FEB-15   CH  4.08    70
37  CSE KEFFLER 01-JAN-15   02-JAN-15   CH      70
34  CSE STRONG  01-APR-14   26-OCT-14   TD  4   70
24  CSE LYNCH   01-APR-14   23-AUG-14   TD  3   70
33  CSE STRONG  11-FEB-14   31-MAR-14   AN      70
29  CSE GARCES  11-DEC-13   31-MAR-14   AN  3.54    70
23  CSE LYNCH   08-FEB-14   31-MAR-14   AN      70
21  CSE SHI     01-APR-13   13-JAN-14   CH  3.69    70
28  CSE DENNEY  01-SEP-13   13-JAN-14   CH  3.92    70
18  CSE SAVOY   01-APR-13   14-NOV-13   EN      70
27  CSE WHITE   01-APR-13   28-JUN-13   GC  2   70
26  CSE WHITE   01-JAN-13   31-MAR-13   AN  2.77    70
17  CSE SAVOY   01-FEB-13   31-MAR-13   AN  2.54    70
20  CSE SHI 01-FEB-13   31-MAR-13   AN  3.15    70
42  CSE                         3.31    70
```

So this query gives results as above. I want to change the query the way its order in such a way that 1st order by dept_id, then order by avg with nulls last and then order by to_date desc.
the average of the dept should be the bottom most. result expected as below:

```
id  dept name   fromDate    toDate      mi  avg dept_id
12  CSE BRADLEY 01-APR-15   25-JUN-15   CH  3.69    70
30  CSE GARCES  01-APR-14   16-FEB-15   TR  3.77    70
25  CSE LYNCH   04-OCT-14   15-FEB-15   CH  3.08    70
35  CSE STRONG  27-NOV-14   15-FEB-15   CH  4.08    70
34  CSE STRONG  01-APR-14   26-OCT-14   TD  4   70
24  CSE LYNCH   01-APR-14   23-AUG-14   TD  3   70
29  CSE GARCES  11-DEC-13   31-MAR-14   AN  3.54    70
21  CSE SHI     01-APR-13   13-JAN-14   CH  3.69    70
28  CSE DENNEY  01-SEP-13   13-JAN-14   CH  3.92    70
27  CSE WHITE   01-APR-13   28-JUN-13   GC  2   70
26  CSE WHITE   01-JAN-13   31-MAR-13   AN  2.77    70
17  CSE SAVOY   01-FEB-13   31-MAR-13   AN  2.54    70
20  CSE SHI     01-FEB-13   31-MAR-13   AN  3.15    70
22  CSE ASHLEY  01-FEB-15   15-JUN-15   EN      70
37  CSE KEFFLER 01-JAN-15   02-JAN-15   CH      70
33  CSE STRONG  11-FEB-14   31-MAR-14   AN          70
23  CSE LYNCH   08-FEB-14   31-MAR-14   AN      70
18  CSE SAVOY   01-APR-13   14-NOV-13   EN      70
42  CSE                         3.31    70
```

I tries this order by

```
'order by dept_id desc, toDate desc nulls last, avg nulls last'
```

it doesnt have any change. Can i apply 2 sets of nulls last ? how do i achieve the output.

Comment: If you're using sqlplus or something that mimics it (e.g., sqlcl), then `set tab off` before you execute the query. Then you can copy the text for pasting in a reasonable fashion.

Comment: @JeffHolt The `DEPT_ID` values are `70` in all the rows (except the last when it is `NULL`) the OP states that in the first sentence and the OP's data shows the same.

Comment: @MT0 I caught that after realizing he's displaying the first sorted column as the last in the table. Not a good UI.

Comment: @javatech, you should name your columns the same in all parts of a union. Otherwise, confusion abounds. And a good UI has sorted columns at the beginning of a row, not the end.

Comment: If you want the result to be ordered by `dept_id` **then** by `avg` with nulls last and **then** by `to_date` desc then you obviously should specify them in this exact order: `order by dept_id desc, avg nulls last, toDate desc nulls last`. But you've swapped date and avg in your order by. Anyway it would be much better to provide desired output for your sample data

Comment: @astentx the expected output is the 2nd table in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the second table and use `ROLLUP`:

```sql
SELECT id,
       MAX(dept) AS dept,
       CASE GROUPING_ID(dept_id, id) WHEN 0 THEN MAX(name) END AS name,
       CASE GROUPING_ID(dept_id, id) WHEN 0 THEN MAX(from_date) END AS from_date,
       CASE GROUPING_ID(dept_id, id) WHEN 0 THEN MAX(to_date) END AS to_date,
       CASE GROUPING_ID(dept_id, id) WHEN 0 THEN MAX(mi) END AS mi,
       ROUND(AVG(avg), 2) AS avg,
       dept_id
FROM   dept_vw vw
GROUP BY ROLLUP(dept_id, id)
HAVING GROUPING_ID(dept_id, id) IN (0, 1)
ORDER BY
       dept_id,
       GROUPING_ID(dept_id, id),
       from_date DESC;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE dept_vw (id, dept, name, from_Date, to_Date, mi, avg, dept_id) AS
SELECT 12, 'CSE', 'BRADLEY', DATE '2015-04-01', DATE '2015-06-25', 'CH', 3.69, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22, 'CSE', 'ASHLEY',  DATE '2015-02-01', DATE '2015-06-15', 'EN', NULL, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 30, 'CSE', 'GARCES',  DATE '2014-04-01', DATE '2015-02-16', 'TR', 3.77, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 25, 'CSE', 'LYNCH',   DATE '2014-10-04', DATE '2015-02-15', 'CH', 3.08, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 35, 'CSE', 'STRONG',  DATE '2014-11-27', DATE '2015-02-15', 'CH', 4.08, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 37, 'CSE', 'KEFFLER', DATE '2015-01-01', DATE '2015-01-02', 'CH', NULL, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 34, 'CSE', 'STRONG',  DATE '2014-04-01', DATE '2014-10-26', 'TD', 4,    70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 24, 'CSE', 'LYNCH',   DATE '2014-04-01', DATE '2014-08-23', 'TD', 3,    70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 33, 'CSE', 'STRONG',  DATE '2014-02-11', DATE '2014-03-31', 'AN', NULL, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 29, 'CSE', 'GARCES',  DATE '2013-12-11', DATE '2014-03-31', 'AN', 3.54, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 23, 'CSE', 'LYNCH',   DATE '2014-02-08', DATE '2014-03-31', 'AN', NULL, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 21, 'CSE', 'SHI',     DATE '2013-04-01', DATE '2014-01-13', 'CH', 3.69, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 28, 'CSE', 'DENNEY',  DATE '2013-09-01', DATE '2014-01-13', 'CH', 3.92, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 18, 'CSE', 'SAVOY',   DATE '2013-04-01', DATE '2013-11-14', 'EN', NULL, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 27, 'CSE', 'WHITE',   DATE '2013-04-01', DATE '2013-06-28', 'GC', 2,    70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 26, 'CSE', 'WHITE',   DATE '2013-01-01', DATE '2013-03-31', 'AN', 2.77, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 17, 'CSE', 'SAVOY',   DATE '2013-02-01', DATE '2013-03-31', 'AN', 2.54, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 'CSE', 'SHI',     DATE '2013-02-01', DATE '2013-03-31', 'AN', 3.15, 70 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | DEPT | NAME | FROM_DATE | TO_DATE | MI | AVG | DEPT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | CSE | BRADLEY | 2015-04-01 00:00:00 | 2015-06-25 00:00:00 | CH | 3.69 | 70 |
| 22 | CSE | ASHLEY | 2015-02-01 00:00:00 | 2015-06-15 00:00:00 | EN | *null* | 70 |
| 37 | CSE | KEFFLER | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 | 2015-01-02 00:00:00 | CH | *null* | 70 |
| 35 | CSE | STRONG | 2014-11-27 00:00:00 | 2015-02-15 00:00:00 | CH | 4.08 | 70 |
| 25 | CSE | LYNCH | 2014-10-04 00:00:00 | 2015-02-15 00:00:00 | CH | 3.08 | 70 |
| 30 | CSE | GARCES | 2014-04-01 00:00:00 | 2015-02-16 00:00:00 | TR | 3.77 | 70 |
| 34 | CSE | STRONG | 2014-04-01 00:00:00 | 2014-10-26 00:00:00 | TD | 4 | 70 |
| 24 | CSE | LYNCH | 2014-04-01 00:00:00 | 2014-08-23 00:00:00 | TD | 3 | 70 |
| 33 | CSE | STRONG | 2014-02-11 00:00:00 | 2014-03-31 00:00:00 | AN | *null* | 70 |
| 23 | CSE | LYNCH | 2014-02-08 00:00:00 | 2014-03-31 00:00:00 | AN | *null* | 70 |
| 29 | CSE | GARCES | 2013-12-11 00:00:00 | 2014-03-31 00:00:00 | AN | 3.54 | 70 |
| 28 | CSE | DENNEY | 2013-09-01 00:00:00 | 2014-01-13 00:00:00 | CH | 3.92 | 70 |
| 21 | CSE | SHI | 2013-04-01 00:00:00 | 2014-01-13 00:00:00 | CH | 3.69 | 70 |
| 18 | CSE | SAVOY | 2013-04-01 00:00:00 | 2013-11-14 00:00:00 | EN | *null* | 70 |
| 27 | CSE | WHITE | 2013-04-01 00:00:00 | 2013-06-28 00:00:00 | GC | 2 | 70 |
| 17 | CSE | SAVOY | 2013-02-01 00:00:00 | 2013-03-31 00:00:00 | AN | 2.54 | 70 |
| 20 | CSE | SHI | 2013-02-01 00:00:00 | 2013-03-31 00:00:00 | AN | 3.15 | 70 |
| 26 | CSE | WHITE | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 | 2013-03-31 00:00:00 | AN | 2.77 | 70 |
| *null* | CSE | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 3.33 | 70 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3Y1gLdkf)

Comment: @MTO thank you so much for the effort. But as per my query in question the avergae comes froma different view. This is a legacy application and that is what im asked to do so cant do a rollup as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column to specify the priority in the ordering:

```sql
SELECT id, dept, name, from_date, to_date, mi, avg, dept_id 
FROM   (
  SELECT id , dept, name, from_date, to_date, mi, avg, dept_id, 1 AS priority
  FROM   dept_vw vw 
UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, dept, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, round(avg,2), dept_id, 2
  FROM   avg_vw
) 
ORDER BY dept_id DESC, priority, to_Date DESC;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dept_vw (id, dept, name, from_Date, to_Date, mi, avg, dept_id) AS
SELECT 12, 'CSE', 'BRADLEY', DATE '2015-04-01', DATE '2015-06-25', 'CH', 3.69, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22, 'CSE', 'ASHLEY',  DATE '2015-02-01', DATE '2015-06-15', 'EN', NULL, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 30, 'CSE', 'GARCES',  DATE '2014-04-01', DATE '2015-02-16', 'TR', 3.77, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 25, 'CSE', 'LYNCH',   DATE '2014-10-04', DATE '2015-02-15', 'CH', 3.08, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 35, 'CSE', 'STRONG',  DATE '2014-11-27', DATE '2015-02-15', 'CH', 4.08, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 37, 'CSE', 'KEFFLER', DATE '2015-01-01', DATE '2015-01-02', 'CH', NULL, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 34, 'CSE', 'STRONG',  DATE '2014-04-01', DATE '2014-10-26', 'TD', 4,    70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 24, 'CSE', 'LYNCH',   DATE '2014-04-01', DATE '2014-08-23', 'TD', 3,    70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 33, 'CSE', 'STRONG',  DATE '2014-02-11', DATE '2014-03-31', 'AN', NULL, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 29, 'CSE', 'GARCES',  DATE '2013-12-11', DATE '2014-03-31', 'AN', 3.54, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 23, 'CSE', 'LYNCH',   DATE '2014-02-08', DATE '2014-03-31', 'AN', NULL, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 21, 'CSE', 'SHI',     DATE '2013-04-01', DATE '2014-01-13', 'CH', 3.69, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 28, 'CSE', 'DENNEY',  DATE '2013-09-01', DATE '2014-01-13', 'CH', 3.92, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 18, 'CSE', 'SAVOY',   DATE '2013-04-01', DATE '2013-11-14', 'EN', NULL, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 27, 'CSE', 'WHITE',   DATE '2013-04-01', DATE '2013-06-28', 'GC', 2,    70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 26, 'CSE', 'WHITE',   DATE '2013-01-01', DATE '2013-03-31', 'AN', 2.77, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 17, 'CSE', 'SAVOY',   DATE '2013-02-01', DATE '2013-03-31', 'AN', 2.54, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 'CSE', 'SHI',     DATE '2013-02-01', DATE '2013-03-31', 'AN', 3.15, 70 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE avg_vw (dept, avg, dept_id) AS
SELECT 'CSE', 3.31, 70 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | DEPT | NAME | FROM_DATE | TO_DATE | MI | AVG | DEPT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | CSE | BRADLEY | 2015-04-01 00:00:00 | 2015-06-25 00:00:00 | CH | 3.69 | 70 |
| 22 | CSE | ASHLEY | 2015-02-01 00:00:00 | 2015-06-15 00:00:00 | EN | *null* | 70 |
| 30 | CSE | GARCES | 2014-04-01 00:00:00 | 2015-02-16 00:00:00 | TR | 3.77 | 70 |
| 25 | CSE | LYNCH | 2014-10-04 00:00:00 | 2015-02-15 00:00:00 | CH | 3.08 | 70 |
| 35 | CSE | STRONG | 2014-11-27 00:00:00 | 2015-02-15 00:00:00 | CH | 4.08 | 70 |
| 37 | CSE | KEFFLER | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 | 2015-01-02 00:00:00 | CH | *null* | 70 |
| 34 | CSE | STRONG | 2014-04-01 00:00:00 | 2014-10-26 00:00:00 | TD | 4 | 70 |
| 24 | CSE | LYNCH | 2014-04-01 00:00:00 | 2014-08-23 00:00:00 | TD | 3 | 70 |
| 33 | CSE | STRONG | 2014-02-11 00:00:00 | 2014-03-31 00:00:00 | AN | *null* | 70 |
| 29 | CSE | GARCES | 2013-12-11 00:00:00 | 2014-03-31 00:00:00 | AN | 3.54 | 70 |
| 23 | CSE | LYNCH | 2014-02-08 00:00:00 | 2014-03-31 00:00:00 | AN | *null* | 70 |
| 21 | CSE | SHI | 2013-04-01 00:00:00 | 2014-01-13 00:00:00 | CH | 3.69 | 70 |
| 28 | CSE | DENNEY | 2013-09-01 00:00:00 | 2014-01-13 00:00:00 | CH | 3.92 | 70 |
| 18 | CSE | SAVOY | 2013-04-01 00:00:00 | 2013-11-14 00:00:00 | EN | *null* | 70 |
| 27 | CSE | WHITE | 2013-04-01 00:00:00 | 2013-06-28 00:00:00 | GC | 2 | 70 |
| 26 | CSE | WHITE | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 | 2013-03-31 00:00:00 | AN | 2.77 | 70 |
| 17 | CSE | SAVOY | 2013-02-01 00:00:00 | 2013-03-31 00:00:00 | AN | 2.54 | 70 |
| 20 | CSE | SHI | 2013-02-01 00:00:00 | 2013-03-31 00:00:00 | AN | 3.15 | 70 |
| *null* | CSE | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 3.31 | 70 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0yNtYXW6)